# Al iniciar pagina, cargar select onchange

Tags: javascript, ajax

Buenas como puedo hacer que al cargar la pagina se active el ajax con el valor actual que tiene el select??

```
$( window ).load(function() {
         /* $("#medidas").each(function() {
            $("#valorPrecio").html($(this).val())
          }); 
          
          $("#medidas").focus();*/

        $('#medidas').on('change',function(){
           $value=$(this).val();
           $medida=$('select[name="medidas"] option:selected').text();

           //console.log($medida);
            $.ajax({                        
                type: "GET",                 
                url : '{{URL::to('medidas')}}',                    
                data:{'idproducto':$value,
                     'medida':$medida},
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $('#valorPrecio').html('<img src="{{ asset('images/loading.gif') }}" class="loading">');
                },
                success: function(data)            
                {
                 $('#valorPrecio').html(data.precio); 

                 if (data.pvpAntes === null){
                    $('#simboloEuro').css("display","none");
                    $('.pvpAntesFIN1').css("display","none");
                 }
                 else{
                    $('.pvpAntesFIN1').html(data.pvpAntes);
                    $('.pvpAntesFIN1').css("display","inline-block");
                    $('#simboloEuro').css("display","inline-block");
                 }              
                 
                 console.log(data);       
               }
             });
        });
    })
```

Comment: No se que versión de jQuery uses pero ese evento load está desaconsejado ya

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para hacerlo deberas usar una funcion con nombre y no una funcion anonima, pero para poder que la funcion anonima tenga nombre deberas separarla de tu `onchange`, por lo tanto tu codigo queda asi:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* $("#medidas").each(function() {
       $("#valorPrecio").html($(this).val())
     }); 
     
     $("#medidas").focus();*/

    function changeSelect(ev){
        $value=$(ev.target).val();
        $medida=$('select[name="medidas"] option:selected').text();

        console.log($value);
        $.ajax({                        
           type: "GET",                 
           url : "{{URL::to('medidas')}}",                    
           data:{'idproducto':$value,
                'medida':$medida},
           beforeSend: function() {
               $('#valorPrecio').html('<img src="{{ asset(\'images/loading.gif\')}}" class="loading">');
           },
           success: function(data)            
           {
            $('#valorPrecio').html(data.precio); 

            if (data.pvpAntes === null){
               $('#simboloEuro').css("display","none");
               $('.pvpAntesFIN1').css("display","none");
            }
            else{
               $('.pvpAntesFIN1').html(data.pvpAntes);
               $('.pvpAntesFIN1').css("display","inline-block");
               $('#simboloEuro').css("display","inline-block");
            }              
            
            console.log(data);       
          }
        });
    }

    $('#medidas').on('change', changeSelect);
    changeSelect({target: $("#medidas")[0]});
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id = "medidas">
  <option value = "hola">hola</option>
  <option value = "mundo">mundo</option>
</select>
```

Tenias comillas mal escapadas, por lo que tuve que corregirlas, si tu las dejas asi javascript no va a interpretar bien el codigo y tu ajax no se ejecutara.

Con respecto a que cambios hice, realmente lo unico que hice fue separar la funcion aparte y le llame `changeSelect` a la cual se le pasa un evento, dentro de esta tambien le hice cambios a:

```
$value=$(ev.target).val();
```

Para que pudiese ser usado mediante un evento ligado o directamente que se le pase el elemento para invocarlo.

por ultimo, esta parte de aqui:

```
$('#medidas').on('change', changeSelect);
changeSelect({target: $("#medidas")[0]});
```

como vemos el evento ahora esta ligado a una funcion con nombre llamada `changeSelect`, ademas, al final usamos de manera directa nuestra funcion pasandole como parametro la simulacion de un evento, de esta manera la funcion hara su trabajo en ambos casos.

Ademas tu tenias:

```
$( window ).load(function() {
```

No creo que tenga mucha relevancia, pero lo cambie a:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

Son practicamente lo mismo, solo que el primero apunta a la ventana y el segundo al documento.

Comment: Brillante funciona de forma perfecta!!!! Muchas gracias @Riven. Una pregunta puedo hacer que el `beforesend` lo haga sobre otro `div` y que cuando reciba el success se vea el resultado?? Esque proble a meterlo todo en un div, para que cuando se cambie la opción no se quede nigún rastro, pero al ponerlo todo en un div, y decir que el beforesend actue ahi, no me devuelve la respuesta

Comment: Eso ya es para otra pregunta Miguel

Answer (score 0):

Intenta utilizando el método [`.trigger()`](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/) sobre el elemento que deseas ejecutar el evento:

```
$(window).ready(function(){
     $('#medidas').trigger('change');
});
```

Este lanzara el evento change y por tanto tu funcion.